# Algebra - Find the equation of the line perpendicular to 3x+2y-4=0 going through point (2,-3)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was wondering if you could help...

I have Math homework, I was hoping if you could check my answer.

Find the equation of the line perpendicular to $3x+2y-4=0$ going through point $(2,-3)$.

$y=\large\frac{-3x+4}{2}$

$y = 2$

$x=-\large\frac{2(y-2)}{3}$

$x=-3$

Therefore my equation is correct?

thanks for you help in advance guys.

Comment: @Jay: the equations you wrote down are both equations for the line you've been given, which passes through (2, -3).  You are supposed to be finding the equation of a _different_ line which also passes through (2, -3).

Comment: If the course for which this is homework is a linear algebra course (a course about vectors and matrices) rather than a secondary-school algebra/advanced algebra/precalculus course or a college algebra course, then I have a different solution method to suggest than the one in my answer.

Comment: @Qiaochu, the original line isn't passing through (2, -3).

Comment: @Jay: Hint: write the general equation of the family of straight lines perpendicular to your given line and use the information that (2,-3) is a point which lies in the unique line perpendicular to it.

Comment: The lines perpendicular to the line $ax+by=c$ all
have the form $bx-ay=d$.

Comment: Use Robin Chapman's second equation and find the contant term.

Comment: OK... It all sort of makes sense. I lied when I said it my homework. My little Sister's. It's all gibberish to me. @Isaac - you're very correct in determining what sort of response is required. I assumed it was the search for Ordered Pairs [x, (-2-(3/2)x)]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If two lines are perpendicular, the product of their slopes is -1.  This is often restated as the slope of the line perpendicular to a given line is the opposite reciprocal of the slope of the given line.  For example, the line $6x-15y+3=0$ has slope $\frac{2}{5}$, so a line perpendicular to it will have slope $-\frac{5}{2}$.

With that fact, you should be able to determine the slope of the line for which you are finding an equation, and you know a point on the line.  Those two pieces of information should be enough for you to write an equation of the line perpendicular to $3x+2y-4=0$ going through point $(2,-3)$.